# would like to get a regex expression for my multi line log

Tags: regex, ibm-mq

I am trying to form the correct regex to capture strings out of a multi line log like -

`AMQ9206: Error sending data to host hic4 (10.254.101.168)(1414).`

or

`AMQ9999: Channel 'TO.MQH4' to host 'HIC4(1414)' ended abnormally.`

multi line log excrepts as follows -

```
06/17/16 22:45:14 - Process(509640.1) User(mqsystem) Program(runmqchl)
                    Host(mqah103p) Installation(MQAppliance)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(PRDCDE3A)

AMQ9206: Error sending data to host hic4 (10.254.101.168)(1414).

--------------------------- amqccita.c : 3166 ----------------------------------

06/17/16 22:45:14 - Process(509640.1) User(mqsystem) Program(runmqchl)
                    Host(mqah103p) Installation(MQAppliance)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(PRDCDE3A)

AMQ9999: Channel 'TO.MQH4' to host 'HIC4(1414)' ended abnormally.
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to clearly show the log along with what you want to extract?

Comment: What programming language is this used with? Regex isn't entirely standardized.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the programming language, this will be expressed slightly differently, but the main trick is to enable **multi-line mode** in your regex. This will allow special characters like `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of a *line* instead of the beginning and end of the string.

Assuming your log always has this general format of `AMQ` followed by 4 numbers, the regex would be something like:

```
/^AMQ\d{4}: .*$/gm
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pA4pZ9/1)

Comment: I think if you used `+` and checked the spaces will be better `/^\s*AMQ\d+:.*$/gm`

Comment: @Meninx it really depends on the format of the log entry, which the OP does not specify.